# Ubuntu 16.04: restore screen refresh rate after suspend/resume

Tags: 16.04, suspend, display-resolution, wakeup

Even after googling, I cannot find an answer to this maybe easy question. One of my computers is connected to the home main TV with a DP/HDMI cable. Everything works fine. The screen resolution is detected the right way, 1920x1080, even if the refresh rate is set to 50Hz (50 Hz interlaced). I can run `xrandr -r 60` and then display a nice 1920x1080@60Hz desktop. (60 Hz progressive).

However, when I stop using the computer for a while, it automatically goes to sleep and, when I wake it up, the resolution is set to this bad 50 Hz interlaced refresh rate.

I added a 15_screen-resume script in /etc/pm/sleep.d as follow :

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume)
        xrandr -r 60
        date > /tmp/resume.txt
    ;;
esac
```

I can check if this script is ran with `date > /tmp/resume.txt` command.  I know this works if I run `pm-suspend` from a shell, wait for the computer to sleep and then wake it up. But this script is not called if the computer enters the sleep mode on its own after a period of inactivity.

Question is: how to call a custom script at wake up after a computer running Ubuntu 16.04 entered the sleep mode after a period of inactivity?

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: This old question came up on my radar today and just wondering how it all turned out??? Thanks~!

Comment: Nothing changed. I still have to change the refresh rate manually. But I did not investigate more. Catching an event when resuming from sleep mode and being able to interact with current graphic session would be so nice.

Answer (score 0):

It can get confusing with the many different ways you can put the computer to sleep with acpi, gnome's gsettings, pm-utils, power management (or something like that) and systemd.

In your case you need to create a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` that looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    xrandr -r 60
    date > /tmp/resume.txt
    ;;
esac
```

To ensure the script is created with the right permissions, copy and existing script and then edit it:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system-sleep
sudo cp wpasupplicant tv_refresh
gksu gedit tv_refresh
```

The `sleep 2` pause may be unnecessary for you but for my setup it was necessary restoring sound from laptop back to HDMI TV.

The `echo` lines are optional but are handy because they show up in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Does not work well. In fact, in get a "Can't open display" error from xrandr. But that's a begining.

Comment: Try increasing slep from 2 seconds to 5 seconds, etc.

Comment: No more luck. Message from xrandr is ``Can't open display :0``. Seems logicial as the script is run out of any graphic interface. I get the same message if I try to run ``xrandr -r 60`` after ``export DISPLAY=:0`` from a shell (text tty1 interface or ssh shell).

Comment: @MaxAuray Just checking in to see if you've managed to get `xrandr -r 60` working on system resume / wake yet?

Comment: nope. I wonder if I would not better try to set the display parameters else where, for example in xorg.conf or something.